# Display same menu for parent and all its children

Tags: menus

I have three main directories in my site, and I'm wanting to display one unique menu for each directory and display it on each child of that directory. I'm thinking I create my three custom menus, but then what would be the best way to display the correct one for each section?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create 3 custom menus and use a conditional.

Example you have 3 custom menus named, Products, Services,Training.

Open the section of the page you want to insert code in the header.php or where ever you need it. file and use:

```
if (is_page( array( 42, 'Products' ) )) {
  wp_nav_menu('menu' => 'Products');
}elseif(is_page( array( 2, 'Services' ) )) {
  wp_nav_menu('menu' => 'Services');
}elseif(is_page( array( 42, 'Training' ) )) {
  wp_nav_menu('menu' => 'Training');
}else {

}
```